# How to activate network card from the CLI in Ubuntu 20.04 server?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-20.04

I have an old Toshiba Satellite PSCP6U-01401E and I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 and Nextcloud to use it as a local file storage.

During installation Ubuntu can't seem to recognize my Wi-Fi card and I tried going through a bunch of tutorials to activate the card to connect to Wi-Fi and it doesn’t seem to work.

On the network connections page I only see an ethernet connection that’s not configured.

I first tired to follow this tutorial: “[Ubuntu 20.04: Connect to WiFi from command line](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line)”

But the wireless LAN isn't available in the first place and I don’t have access to an ethernet port at the moment.

I then tried these links to no avail:

- “[How to enable wireless on Ubuntu Server 20.04 via CLI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255866/how-to-enable-wireless-on-ubuntu-server-20-04-via-cli)”
- “[How to Enable Wi-Fi on Ubuntu Server 20.04 without a Wired Ethernet Connection](https://medium.com/@yping88/how-to-enable-wi-fi-on-ubuntu-server-20-04-without-a-wired-ethernet-connection-42e0b71ca198)”

How can I access/activate the network card from the CLI?

`/etc/netplan/00-netcfg.yaml` only shows

```
network:
  ethernet: {}
  version: 2
```

`ls /sys/class/net` does not show any WLANs:

```
lo enp0s25
```

`lspci` info:

[image]

Comment: Details about your laptop make and model would help. Also, what is the output of "lspci"?  The first step is to identify the WiFi card and then ensure there is an appropriate driver for it.

Comment: I believe its a Toshiba Satellite Part No. PSCP6U-01401E
Also I'm not sure how to get the ispci info

Comment: Type "sudo lspci" and take a picture of the output?

Comment: Added the information as a picture, the network controller information
01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.111b/g/n (rev 01)

Comment: At this point I can't provide step-by-step instructions, but you have narrowed down the problem space somewhat - we know you have a BCM43142 based WiFi, so you need to enable that. It looks like you will need to install a package to do it.   If you have an Ethernet connection working, try do a " sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms" to install the required driver, otherwise maybe you can get it from https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-multiverse-amd64/broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-12_all.deb.html - copy it on a pen drive and use...

Comment: "dpkg -i /mwdia/???/broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-12_all.deb" to install it.  Once its installed, reboot and advise what "ls /sys/class/net" shows. With some luck though WIFI might just start working.

Comment: ah looks like ethernet is the only solution i can find.  I unfortunately dont have access to one at the current moment, i'll have to wait a few days.  I appreciate the help!